# ¿Cómo asignar el valor seleccionado de un radio button a un campo en la base de datos?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Hola me gustaría saber como puedo hacer para indicar si un campo contiene o no determinada propiedad, un ejemplo para que quede más claro sería que por ejemplo "¿Tiene baño compartido?" si el radio **button1** es presionado entonces tendría que decir **si** y si el segundo botón radio es presionado tendría que ser **no**, lo he planteado de la siguiente manera pero no me funciona:

```
If(radio1.checked){
    bañoCompartido = true;
}else if(radio2.checked){
    bañoCompartido = false;
}
```

No me doy cuenta de qué puedo estar haciendo mal, gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y cómo has definido tu pregunta la respuesta correcta es:

```
if (radio1.checked) bañoCompartido = true;

if (radio2.checked) bañoCompartido = false;
```

Esto lo que hace es: Si el `radio1` es seleccionado, en *principio* será compartido. Si el `radio2` es seleccionado, **nunca** será compartido.

Otra manera de hacerlo en una sola línea:

```
bañoCompartido = radio1.checked && !radio2.checked;
```

Y por último, destacar que el uso de la **Ñ** en una variable me sorprende. **Desaconsejo** su uso enormemente. Por una parte no sabía ni que te permitía compilar y por otra nadie te garantiza que esa letra esté disponible en un teclado fuera de España/País de habla hispana/país con habla que contenga la Ñ.

Answer (score 2):

La programación incluye las buenas prácticas, debes tener cuidado con las mayúsculas y minúsculas al igual que el uso de letras y símbolos que no se usan en otros países, tal como las "ñ", las "tildes", etc al momento de programar, ya que significan cosas diferentes (son palabras reservadas que tienen su función individual en el caso de las mayúsculas y minúsculas, así como la mala interpretación de la compilación del software, en el caso de las "ñ", etc.)

Un consejo, puedes evitar tantas líneas de código con esta simple línea:

```
banoCompartido = radio1.IsChecked == true ? true : false;
```

El error que tienes en tu código es que usas un evento en el radioButton, el cual es "Checked", lo correcto es condicionar con "IsChecked" ya que el resultado es booleano... Usa la línea que te puse y me cuentas cómo te fue.

Answer (score 0):

yo recorro todos los controles que sean radiobutton y elijo el que está chequeado. Dentro de la propiedad Tag le asigno el valor que necesito recuperar

```
 foreach (Control rdbdedo in this.Controls)
    {
        if (rdbdedo.GetType() == typeof(RadioButton))
        {
            if ((RadioButton)rdbdedo.Checked)
            {
                return rdbdedo.Tag;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Desde las propiedades podrías dejar uno seleccionado por defecto.

Así sólo ocuparías un `if` con su `else`:

```
if(radio1.checked)
{
    bañoCompartido = true;
}
else
{
    bañoCompartido = false;
}
```

Importante; `If` no es igual que `if` (Cuida el uso de mayúsculas y minúsculas)